# How to extract Lambda and Nu parameters from glmmTMB Conway-Maxwell Poisson regression model

Tags: r, model, poisson, glmmtmb

I'm trying to build Conway Maxwell Poisson model with `glmmTMB` package with model's `family = "compois"`. The model works okay but I cannot find any output from the model that expresses the Conway-Maxwell's `Lambda` and `Nu` parameters which hinders me to run Conway-Maxwell random number generator for simulation

Some simple codes to illustrate this

```
install.packages("COMPoissonReg")
install.packages("glmmTMB")
library(COMPoissonReg)
library(glmmTMB)

#Create artificial COM poisson count data as response variable
data <- data.frame(Response = rcmp(5000, lambda = 3, nu = 2))
#Create artificial poisson count data as explanatory variable
data$Covariate <- rpois(5000, lambda = 1)*data$Response

#Run ConwayMaxwellPois glmmTMB regression model
Mod <- glmmTMB(Response ~ Covariate, 
               family = "compois",
               data = data)
summary(Mod)

#Check Models structure
str(Mod)

#Predict mu
predict(Mod, type = "response")
#Predict dispersion parameters
predict(Mod, type = "disp")
```

The `predict(Mod, type = "response")` returns the actual mean which is not the lambda, and the `predict(Mod, type = "disp")` returns small decimal values which I think those are not the Nu (I've read from some sources that the actual Nu is `1/predict(Mod, type = "disp")` but I'm not sure if this is actually true).

Answer (score 2):

`1/predict(Mod, type = "disp")` is nu. Your simulated data doesn't have nu=2 because this
`data$Covariate <- rpois(5000, lambda = 1)*data$Response`
doesn't follow the equation for a GLM with a log-link.

Have you considered using the `simulate()` function built into `glmmTMB`? It could simulate from your fitted model. There's an example on page 392 [here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-066/RJ-2017-066.pdf)

Otherwise, eqn 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03214.pdf) in Huang 2017 defines lambda. You can use the `uniroot()` function to solve the equation for lambda given each value of mu. Sum up to a high value of y, not infinity; then try a higher value of y to confirm that the solution doesn't change. If it changes, then sum up to a higher value of y and try again.

Comment: So is this the correct setup? `data <- data.frame(Response = rcmp(5000, lambda = 8, nu = 1));
Mod <- glmmTMB(Response ~ 1, family = "compois",data = data);
mu <- predict(Mod, type = "response");
nu <- 1/summary(Mod)$sigma;
y <- 0:100
Vfunc <- Vectorize( function(x){sum(  (y -  mu) * (x^y)/(factorial(y))^nu ) } );
uniroot(Vfunc, c(0, 10) )  `  I'm not 100% sure how to determine the required length of ys?